# Como identificar se foi digitado um número no vetor

Tags: java, array

> Escreva um programa que solicite ao usuário a entrada de 6 números de um bilhete de loteria  em um vetor e posteriormente verifique se existe o número 25 nessa sequência de  números passados pelo usuário.

Estou com uma dúvida, não sei como fazer para identificar se existe o número 25, se foi digitado pelo usuário.

Segue o comando que eu fiz

```java
public class Ex04 {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        int [] num = new int [6];
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
            num[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira o número do bilhete: "));  
        }    
        for (Integer integer : num) {
            System.out.print(integer + ", ");
        }                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> A primeira que coisa que você deve fazer é criar a variável, que você
>   deseja encontrar, desta forma:

```java
//Número procurado: 
int numeroProcurado = 25;
```

> Em segundo lugar, criar a variável do tipo booelana que vai receber
>   true ou false, true caso o número seja encontrado, falso, caso
>   contrário:

```java
//Uma flag para verificar se existe:
        boolean vinteCincoExiste = false;

        for (Integer numero : num) {

            if (numero == numeroProcurado) {
                vinteCincoExiste = true;
            }

        }
```

> E, por último, faça o teste para verificar se realmente existe ou
>   não, desta forma:

```java
//Se a variável vinteCincoExiste for igual a true, então, existe.
 if (vinteCincoExiste) {
            System.out.println("o número " + numeroProcurado + " existe.");
        }
else{ //Caso contrário, não existe.
 System.out.println("o número " + numeroProcurado + " não existe.");
}
```

**Teste não encontrado:**
Entradas: 2,6,4,8,9,10
Saída: o número 25 não existe.

**Teste com sucesso:**
Entradas: 2,6,25,8,9,10
Saída: o número 25 existe.

> **Demo:**

https://repl.it/@TaffarelXavier/SlowOptimisticStack

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um arrayList, pois nele tem um método pra procurar valores`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * FindNumber
 */
public class FindNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println(array.contains(25));
    }
}`
```